# how to unset NODE_OPTIONS in firebase hosting CICD?

Tags: firebase, vue.js

facing digital envelope routines::unsupported error in firebase hosting and local but in local I resolved that issue using unset NODE_OPTIONS cmd but I don't know how can I use this in firebase Hosting CICD

[image]